# C++ brace enclosed initializer list in delegate constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization

I am trying to provide two different constructors for a c++ class including a std::vector member:

```
class A {

    public:

        std::vector<int> p;

        A (std::vector<int> i) { p = i; }

        A (int x, int y, int z) : A ( {x, y, z} ) {}
};

int main () {

    A a ( {1, 2, 3} );

    A a2 (1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The first constructor works ok, but the second one throws the following error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
```

Which is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: You can read [the notes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72bc6715d2140911).

Comment: Of course it's ambiguous. `{x, y, z}` Can both create a temporary `A` from which our current `A` is to be copied/moved, or a `vector` from which `A` is to be constructed. How is the compiler supposed to choose?

Comment: When you get errors, always read the *full* error message. There might often be informational notes that should help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second constructor:

```
A (int x, int y, int z) : A ( {x, y, z} ) {}
```

Since `A ( {x,y,z} )` can call both

- the first constructor: the initialise list `{x, y, z}` can be cast into a `std::vector<int>` and matching the first constructor.
- the second constructor itself: as you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/7ZGS75) where the constructor calls itself:

---

```
A::A(int, int, int):
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $8, %esp
// ...
call    A::A(int, int, int)  // <--- recursive call
// ...
```

---

> Which is the difference between the two methods?

The first constructor accepts any vectors of integers. Valid constructions are, for example:

```
A({1}); A({1, 2}); A({1, 2, 4}); A({1, 2, 3, 4, ...}); ...
```

The second constructor accepts three integers. Valid constructions are:

```
A({1, 2, 3}); A(1, 2, 3); A{1, 2, 3};
```

As you can see the expression `A({1, 2, 3})` is accepted by both constructors and so it is ambiguous (the compiler cannot know, in a deterministic way, which choose).

Comment: I see it now. I didn't know that {1,2,3} was valid to construct three integers alone. Is there any way to specify which one to call to break this ambiguity? Or should I just use a different function instead of the second constructor?

Comment: @derkomai you can add an explicit braced-init list constructor: `A(std::initializer_list<int> i) : p(i) {}`

Comment: That's just what I was looking for!

Comment: @derkomai It strongly depends on what you what to do. From your question (without any other context information) the second constructor seems to be useless. By the way, providing more context I suggest you to open another question about that. Finally the idea of an `initializer_list`is a valid option.